# CMD: How to escape this powershell command in cmd?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following powershell command:

```
(gc c:\foo.xml -Raw) -replace '(?s)(.*)<bar baz="foo" />', '$1LOL' | Out-File c:\foo.xml
```

I know verified this powershell command works when I type it in a PowerShell.

Now I want to run it from cmd prompt, so I know I need to do in cmd:

```
powershell -Command [the-above-powershell-command]
```

However, the powershell command has so many special characters that no matter what escapes I use, I cannot get it right.

Can someone escape the powershell command for me so I can put it in cmd?

Comment: Perhaps you're not aware, but you don't need to run it from `cmd.exe`. Just use PowerShell and run the PowerShell command directly from the PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself:

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\foo.xml -Raw) -replace '(?s)(.*)<bar baz=\"foo\" />', '$1LOL' | Out-File c:\foo.xml"
```

The trick is to escape " with \, not with ".

[Link](http://www.tinyint.com/index.php/2011/04/20/escaping-quotes-in-powershell-exe-command-via-command-prompt/) that helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to Base64 encode the command and use the `-EncodedCommand` switch:

```
$CmdLine = @'
(gc c:\foo.xml -Raw) -replace '(?s)(.*)<bar baz="foo" />', '$1LOL' | Out-File c:\foo.xml
'@
$CmdLineBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($CmdLine)
$EncodedCommand = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CmdLineBytes)
```

This will, in your case, result in the string:

```
KABnAGMAIABjADoAXABmAG8AbwAuAHgAbQBsACAALQBSAGEAdwApACAALQByAGUAcABsAGEAYwBlACAAJwAoAD8AcwApACgALgAqACkAPABiAGEAcgAgAGIAYQB6AD0AIgBmAG8AbwAiACAALwA+ACcALAAgACcAJAAxAEwATwBMACcAIAB8ACAATwB1AHQALQBGAGkAbABlACAAYwA6AFwAZgBvAG8ALgB4AG0AbAA=
```

Calling it from `cmd`:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand KABnAGMAIABjADoAXABmAG8AbwAuAHgAbQBsACAALQBSAGEAdwApACAALQByAGUAcABsAGEAYwBlACAAJwAoAD8AcwApACgALgAqACkAPABiAGEAcgAgAGIAYQB6AD0AIgBmAG8AbwAiACAALwA+ACcALAAgACcAJAAxAEwATwBMACcAIAB8ACAATwB1AHQALQBGAGkAbABlACAAYwA6AFwAZgBvAG8ALgB4AG0AbAA=
```

Comment: This is very nice!